# Copy Formula from on adding new row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I just want a google sheet script so when I add a new row after row 2 in row 3, then it's copy formula which is some specific cells like ( col b, Col c, and col d ). Attaching a screenshot for reference. Please help, new to this google sheet scripts.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

OK, so if I'm correct you just want to copy the row's formatting for every new row created, and I'm assuming you want to insert a new row always on top of the others (always on row 2 or 3) right?

For that you can easily start a recording of a new macro (through the **Tools** menu), then:

- Select a full row by clicking on it's number (let's take row `3` for example);
- Copy it with `ctrl+c`;
- Create a new row above it (your row `3` is now on row `4`)
- Select the new empty row `3` just as before;
- And **special paste** it, by using `ctrl+shift+v`, which allows you to copy only the cells' format, but not its data.

After that you can end your recording by saving it. If you don't want to manually run this script everytime by selecting it, you can setup a shortcut for it, which has to be `ctrl+alt+shift+a_number`.

If you want to see what the scrpit looks like after it's ready, you can access the **Script Editor** through the **Tools** menu. You can learn a lot of how it works for future projects you may have, and will make it easier to grasp the idea of how to do something else using the script editor.